# Docker Socket Without TLS

Tags: ssl, docker

I have a TLS secured docker demon running. I use TLS for remote accessing the docker demon and access docker locally without any TLS. Normally...

Recently, I have updated Docker. Apparently I cannot connect to the local socket anymore. I suppose Docker is using now TLS for remote and local connections.

Is there a way to disable TLS for the local Docker socket?

Output of `ps auxw | grep dockerd`:

/usr/bin/dockerd -H 0.0.0.0:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert /home/dockermanager/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert /home/dockermanager/.docker/server-cert.pem --tlskey /home/dockermanager/.docker/server-key.pem

Comment: It's not clear to me that you configure the daemon to use TLS on one interface but not another (at least not based on a cursory inspection of the docs, although I'm definitely not claiming I'm correct on this :).  Would it be simpler to just bite the bullet and register the cert with your local client?

Comment: It's also not clear to me, that's why I post my question. I have several cron containers running with specific docker commands. That's a lot to migrate.

Comment: Please include the output of `ps auxw | grep dockerd` and `cat /etc/docker/daemon.json`

Comment: Done. Don't have a daemon.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had been able to fix this myself.

I needed to migrate to these two systemd files provided by Docker:
https://github.com/moby/moby/tree/master/contrib/init/systemd

One service file is for the docker demon and there is one for the docker socket separately. The docker socket is a required dependency by docker.service and will be loaded, restartet and stopped accordingly.

Then i needed to add the docker demon parameter `-H unix://` in order to activate the docker demon listening to the docker socket.

Afterwards everything worked as always and I assume local docker.socket communication does not need tls verification at all.

Start command now:

```
/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert /home/dockeruser/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert /home/dockeruser/.docker/server-cert.pem --tlskey /home/dockeruser/.docker/server-key.pem
```